Chemical Handwritten Notes OCR
I am trying to get my chemical notes digitized (into formats like the ones we see in textbooks). I have tried Mathpix and it works like a charm but I do not have the money to pay for it.
Does anyone know of any other OCR tools for chemical reactions? Now I have tried the general OCR tools like Tesseract which is barely able to process the diagrams and provide accurate results.
I've tried various forms of preprocessing via OpenCV, including threshes, blurs, kernels etc. However, there is no improvement, with Tesseract picking up 1-2 characters and often returning nothing at all.
You can assume that the handwriting is fairly proper and upload quality of image is good.
Any advice on this is highly appreciated even if it just points me in a general direction.

You might find it worthwhile to read https://aclanthology.org/2024.lrec-main.1110.pdf which highlights some of the difficulties of OCR on chemical formulae (let alone handwritten formulae or reaction diagrams.

I would suggest that a good starting point to train your own model for your subject area, (Chemical Reactions rather than Maths Equations) and handwriting would be pix2tex - LaTeX OCR - you will need to train the software as mentioned and this will probably take several days in total, (creating the training data and then running the training).

Thanks for the insights. I actually want to use a pre-built software to do this rather than train a model with lots of data (finding a lot of annotated data will take time) and then fine-tune it (hopefully trying to increase accuracy of the results). Also the training itself will take a lot of time depending on the amount of data and architecture I would be using. Hence, asked for a recommendation for a software or github repo if it is already there.
